# PDFMerger v1.0 fails using FPDF 1.6 and FPDI 1.3.1 with SSLv3 disabled

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

Disabling SSLv3 on our web server caused this error:

> FDPF error: Unable to find pointer to xref table

We're using the PDFMerger class which also user FPDF 1.6 and FPDI 1.3.1 and the only way it works is when SSLv3 is enabled. Our temporary solution is to keep SSLv3 enabled until we can resolve it.

How can we resolve this without having SSLv3 enabled (the more recent POODLE attacks required us to disable it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating the FPDF and FPDI libraries. I don't know exactly why it works, but it does even with SSLv3 disabled.

I started a github repo with the updated libraries:
https://github.com/chrsc/pdfmerger